# What are "Secondary Orbital Interactions" in Organic Chemistry?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals, resonance

We used these to analyze the stability of molecules in an Organic Chemistry Course.
My teacher analyses the stability of compounds on 3 levels:

1. Atom level by studying the hybridization of the main atom
2. Secondary Orbital Interactions: he first draws a good resonance structure, he identifies candidates that participate in the stabilization (Candidates are often a Pi or Sigma Bond) then
3. He draws the Energy Diagram of the Secondary Orbital Interaction.

But I can't see what Secondary Orbital Interactions are, and why do we draw their Energy Diagram?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include examples of some molecules or structures that your teacher used to describe the secondary orbital interactions?